# dataframe from underlying script not updating

Tags: python, dataframe, reference

I have a script called "RiskTemplate.py" which generates a pandas dataframe consisting of 156 columns.  I created two additional columns which gives me a total count of 158 columns.  However, when I run this "RiskTemplate.py" script in another script using the below code, the dataframe only pulls the original 156 columns I had before the two additional columns were added.

**exec(open("RiskTemplate.py").read())**

how can I get the reference script to pull in the revised dataframe from the underlying script "RiskTemplate.py"?

here are the lines creating the two additional dataframe columns, they work as intended when I run it directly in the "RiskTemplate.py" script.  The original dataframe is pulling from SQL via **df = pd.read_sql(query,connection)**

df['LMV % of NAV'] = df['longmv']/df['End of Month NAV']*100

df['SMV % of NAV'] = df['shortmv']/df['End of Month NAV']*100

Comment: Can you add the lines in which you create the dataframe and add the two columns? would be benefitial as a starting point to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, sorry for the confusion.  I did not save the risktemplate that I updated the dataframe to in the same folder that the other reference script was looking at!  Newbie!